# jquery mobile on phonegap backbutton event

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
    if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") === "home") {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.app.exitApp(); //not working
    }
}
```

My `onBackKeyDown()` function is being entered, now I'm getting a series of strange events:

1. My if condition is never entered, even when my `$.mobile.activePage.attr("id") === "home"` is true (tested on weinre server)
2. navigator.app.exitApp never works, this seems to happen across my whole app, not just this one function.
3. Back button is unresponsive all over my app.

Any idea why I'm getting this strange behavior? Phonegap 2.6, jquery mobile 1.3.0 and testing on an Android 2.3.7.

Comment: How do you call that function and when?

Answer (score 0):

In my testing here

```
if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") === "home") {
```

works perfectly.

Already "navigator.app.exitApp ()" will not really work because "navigator" refers to the browser itself, PhoneGap applications do not use browser but a webview.

But how applications behave differently on each OS version, try the following:

```
if(navigator.app){
        navigator.app.exitApp();
}else if(navigator.device){
        navigator.device.exitApp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing html5 app with cordova and jquery mobile - for Android and Blackberry the following code working for me :

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
window.device = {
iphone: ua.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/),
blackberry7: ua.match(/91|93|97|96|97|9800|9810|9850|9860|99/),
blackberry10: ua.match(/BB|PlayBook|Tablet/),
android: ua.match(/Android/)
}
//window.device ready for blackberry
if (window.device.blackberry7){
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
}
//window.device ready for android
else {
    window.addEventListener('load', onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

and then :

```
function onDeviceReady(){
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("searchbutton", onSearchKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown(){
if (window.device.blackberry7){blackberry.app.exit();}
if (!window.device.blackberry7){navigator.app.exitApp();}
}
function onMenuKeyDown(){
if (window.device.blackberry7){alert("BB Menu key");}
if (!window.device.blackberry7){alert("Menu key");}
}
function onSearchKeyDown(){
if (window.device.blackberry7){alert("BB Search key");}
if (!window.device.blackberry7){alert("Search key");}
}
```